# How to split a list in brackets by a comma

Tags: python

Use for loop to print each name with the first name first and the last name last using this "names" list. here is what I have so far:

```
names = ['Bryan, Thomas', 'Ash, Marcus', 'Peter, Ryann']
for i in names:
    comma = names.split(", ")
    lastName = names [:comma]
    firstName = names[comma+2:]
    finalName = firstName + " " +lastName
    print(finalName)
```

I keep getting an error saying AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split' or list indices must be integers or slices, not str.

Comment: 1) Every line after your `for` loop should be indented. 2) That line that is erroring should read `comma = i.split(", ")` since you want to split the name, not the list `names`. 3) `names[:comma]` makes no sense. `comma` is a list containing the lastname as the first element and the firstname as the second element (not an integer). Instead `lastName = comma[0]` and `firstName = comma[1]`

Answer (score 2):

You have couple of issues in your code,

```
In [1]: names = ['Bryan, Thomas', 'Ash, Marcus', 'Peter, Ryann']
    ...: for i in names: 
    ...:     name = i.split(", ") # Split each element in the loop
    ...:     lastName = name[0] # Access element
    ...:     firstName = name[1]
    ...:     finalName = firstName + " " +lastName
    ...:     print(finalName)
    ...: 
Thomas Bryan
Marcus Ash
Ryann Peter
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to call `split` on the `list` itself, not individual elements. If you just want to split the elements, rearrange and print them, you want:

```
names = ['Bryan, Thomas', 'Ash, Marcus', 'Peter, Ryann']
for name in names:  # Use name, not i; these aren't integers and i is misleading
    last, first = name.split(', ')  # Split the current name, not the whole list
                                    # and unpack the result (assumed two items precisely)
    final_name = first + ' ' + last # Stick them back together with a space
                                    # f'{first} {last}' would be slightly nicer
    print(final_name)
```